# VSCode c++ exception before main

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, dll

So I got a main.cpp which loops precisely like this:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it. Launch debug via VScode. I then see the following in the Debug Console:

```
... //loading of dll:s 
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. 
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB3293CF19 in main.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: win32::Win32Error at memory location 0x000000000014EBA0.
Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\fltLib.dll'. 
... //loading of dll:s
The program '[28064] main.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

What could cause the exception and should I worry/bother?

If I actually put some code in the program everything works as expected. I just don't like to see random exceptions thrown

Comment: I have a feeling that more info is needed to be able to help you with this. have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: well actually it is when I'm using the debugger I notice the exception. Other than that I notice no errors. What other info could be beneficial for the investigation?